# Zoho CRM API simpleXMLelement get multiple product IDs

Tags: php, object, simplexml, crm, zoho

I am working with the Zoho CRM api and I was able to extract the product ID when only inserting one product, but can't figure out how to do it with multiple products. https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/insertrecords.html#Insert_Multiple_records

I convert the response to simpleXMLElement and I can get the first product ID easily with:

```
...curl stuff
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$product_id = $xml->result->recorddetail->FL[0];
```

The question is if I have multiple product ID's sent back how would I get each one in a loop as my code will only return the first product ID successfully.  This is an example of the response from 2 products inserted in the api and the returned response:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [uri] =>    
/crm/private/xml/Products/insertRecords ) [result] => SimpleXMLElement 
Object ( [message] => Record(s) added successfully [recorddetail] => Array ( 
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [FL] => Array ( [0] => **2389399000000122065** 
[1] => 2017-03-12 21:33:50 [2] => 2017-03-12 21:33:50 [3] => 
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [val] => Created By ) ) 
[4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [val] => Modified 
By ) ) ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [FL] => Array ( [0] =>   
**2389399000000122066** [1] => 2017-03-12 21:33:50 [2] => 2017-03-12 21:33:50   
[3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [val] => Created 
By ) ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [val] => 
Modified By ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Not sure if it shows up in bold but the two values enclosed in ** ** is what I am looking to extract.

Comment: In questions like this, it's best to show a sample of the actual XML, rather than SimpleXML, because `print_r`/`var_dump` doesn't cope very well with SimpleXML, and from the XML anyone can reproduce your code to check their solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this is to understand that this:

```
$xml->result->recorddetail->FL[0];
```

Is just shorthand for this:

```
$xml->result[0]->recorddetail[0]->FL[0];
```

That should make it obvious that to access the 2nd `recorddetail` (with index `1`), you could write this:

```
$xml->result->recorddetail[1]->FL[0];
```

Because of the magic SimpleXML provides you can also find out how many there are:

```
count($xml->result->recorddetail);
```

And most relevantly for your case, loop over them:

```
foreach ( $xml->result->recorddetail as $recorddetail ) {
    $product_id = $recorddetail->FL[0];
}
```

As a final tip, you probably want the `$product_id` variable to hold an ordinary string, not a SimpleXML object; you get that with a "string cast", like this:

```
$product_id = (string)$recorddetail->FL[0];
```

Comment: Thank you IMSoP, solution works perfectly and much easier to understand now thanks to your detailed explanation!